# how to wait for function to finish execution before calling it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function:

```
<script>
    function func(i){
       $("."+i).html("<h1>this is sample</h1>");
    }
</script>
```

and another place in the body I have to call it

```
<script>    
    while(i<10){
       func(i);
       i++;
    }
</script>
```

Now what I want is the function to call every time it has finish execution but I can't find a way.I can't call the function from the function body as I have variable to pass from the calling function that is changing.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't quite get what you are trying to achieve, but instead of waiting for a function to finish you can pass a callback function  to original function so that it gets called when the main function finishes. This callback can even call the main function again.

Comment: You existing implementation should work. there is nothing asynchronous